# How to check the units from ASE get_forces() function?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, atomic-simulation-environment, intermolecular-forces

Here is a little python code that loops through a molecular dynamics trajectory (performed with the ASE package) and outputs the forces on the atoms at each frame:

```
from ase.io import read
traj = read('output.traj', index=':')

counter = 0
for atoms in traj:
    forces = atoms.get_forces()
    print("forces: ",forces)

    print("counter: ", counter)
    counter = counter + 1
```

This is all well and good... but I'm not sure what the units are on the forces that are outputted.

According to the documentation, the units from `get_forces()` depends on the calculator that is attached to the `atoms` object: [Docs_get_forces](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/atoms.html#ase.Atoms.get_forces)

But I didn't specify a calculator in my little code snippet and it outputted the forces anyway. I tried to check the calculator used by adding these lines:

```
calculator = atoms.get_calculator()
print(calculator)
```

According to this, the calculator attached to my atoms is `SinglePointCalculator`. But when I looked up the source code for this calculator, I can't find where the `get_forces()` calculation is being done, or any of the units associated with it.

TLDR; What are the default force units outputted by ASE?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: ASE typically uses $eV/Å$ for force measurements. But for the `SinglePointCalculator`: *forces are stored*, not calculated. Consequently, the forces you get via `get_forces()` are contingent on the units specified in the originating simulation.

Comment: Thank you very much!